# How do I format this dynamic generated html table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to render 4 columns from a mysql query but I cannot properly align the output values, how can I format the table, so all 4 columns and headers to align center?

```
$tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px"; 
$tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 

echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">'; 
echo "<tr align='center'> <th>Title</th><th>Score</th><th>Maximum Score</th><th>Finished On</th></tr>";

$row = $database->loadRowList();
foreach($row as $valuearray)
{
echo '<tr style=" align="center">';
foreach($valuearray as $field)
{

echo "<td align='center'>$field</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your table with data with in another table which has one cell and center it so that the HTML looks something like this:

```
<table><tr align='center' valign='middle'><td><table>...</table></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: How about the columns, would that inherit all headers and body cells center?

Comment: Your table remains entact and unchanged. What it does is center your table within a larger cell. Here is an example: <table width="100%"><tr align=center valign=middle><td><table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0):

```
$tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px"; 

$tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 

echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">'; 
echo "<tr> <th align='center'>Title</th><th align='center'>Score</th><th align='center'>Maximum Score</th><th align='center'>Finished On</th></tr>";

$row = $database->loadRowList();
foreach($row as $valuearray)
{
echo '<tr>';
foreach($valuearray as $field)
{

echo "<td align='center'>$field</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Align center should not be placed over tr